Binding redirect not applying
I have a .NET framework 4.6.1 project that uses playwright to interact with a web page. When I try to connect to the webpage I get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
In the fusion logs I see "LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 6.0.0.0 redirected to 6.0.0.9". So I added a binding redirect to the version I installed via nuget, it looks like this:
However, my binding redirect looks like this:
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

I rebuild the project and run it again but I still get the same error messages. Is there something else I need to do to get the binding redirect to take effect?

https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/

Maybe it's <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.9" />

@jeb I tried that and also got an error message. Also the version of System.Text.Json I can get from nuget is 6.0.0.0 not 6.0.0.9.
